# Change the variable to the coming function from before plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I would like to change the variable - $validate to false from before the plugin. May I know how to do it?

app/code/MyModule/ReviewCheck/Plugin/ReviewModel.php

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\ReviewCheck\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManagerInterface;

class ReviewModel {

protected $messageManager;

protected $request;

public function __construct(
    MessageManagerInterface  $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
)
{
    $this->messageManager=$messageManager;
    $this->request=$request;

}

public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post $subject) {

    $nickNameChecker = $this->request->getPostValue("nickname");


    if(strpos($nickNameChecker,"-")){

        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Nickname cant has dash'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    }
    else {
        return $this;
    }

   }
}
```

\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 namespace Magento\Review\Controller\Product;

 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
 use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 use Magento\Review\Model\Review;

 /**
  * Class Post
  */
 class Post extends ProductController implements HttpPostActionInterface
 {
/**
 * Submit new review action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
    if ($data) {
        $rating = [];
        if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
            $rating = $data['ratings'];
        }
    } else {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
    }
    if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
        /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
        $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
        $review->unsetData('review_id');

        $validate = $review->validate();
        if ($validate === true) {
            ....
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to $validate in `execute` method in `Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post` class being the result of `validate` method in `Magento\Review\Model\Review`, you should modify `validate` method in `Magento\Review\Model\Review` instead.

You also need to use `after` plugin instead of `before` plugin for that method.

So, declare the plugin in `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Review\Model\Review">
        <plugin name="AddCustomValidation" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\AddCustomValidation"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Plugin/AddCustomValidation.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

class AddCustomValidation
{
    public function afterValidate(\Magento\Review\Model\Review $subject, $result)
    {
        $nickName = $subject->getNickname() ?? '';
        if (is_array($result) && $result && strpos($nickName, '-')) {
            $result[] = __('Nickname cant has dash.') . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        if ($result === true && strpos($nickName, '-')) {
            $result = __('Nickname cant has dash.') . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Remove `generated` directory and clear cache to get it done.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code as per your advice but showed error: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyModule\ReviewCheck\Plugin\ReviewModel::afterValidate() must be an instance of MyModule\ReviewCheck\Plugin\Magento\Review\Model\Review,

Comment: It's a small typo, replace Magento\Review\Model\Review with `\Magento\Review\Model\Review` in app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Plugin/AddCustomValidation.php. Remove `generated` directory and clear cache.